# Rails server goes down frequently in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I'm using Rails 3.0.5 version and Ruby 1.9.2 in my application.

Its working fine in development mode but in production mode server goes down after every 3-4 days.

It gives below error in `/var/log/https/error.log file`.

```
[Sun Oct 21 09:39:03 2012] [error] [IP_ADDRESS] **Premature end of script headers:** 
[ pid=24971 thr=1 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:817 time=2012-10-21 09:39:03.371 ]:
```

The backed application (process 29805) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.

I am not getting what's the reason for server down.

Answer (score 0):

which server your using? webrick or else? i got some problem like this in past that server goes down. i changed server from webrick to Mongrel its faster then webrick

Comment: I am using apache as a web server and phusion passenger as a application server.

Comment: Is there any problem of PassengerUseGlobalQueue parameter in passenger conf?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't comment so answering, personally haven't come across this problem but there seems to be quite some talk about it. Here are a few resources that i came across:

1. [Dalibor Nasevic's explanation as to why this is happening](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/7-premature-end-of-script-headers-ruby-on-rails-with-phusion-passenger-on-apache-error)
2. [Premature end of script headers — Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732765/premature-end-of-script-headers-rails)
3. [Intermittent “premature end of script headers” with Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358280/intermittent-premature-end-of-script-headers-with-rails-3-1)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read all links and also implement the solutions but still this is not helpful for me..

Comment: I am getting problem in memory leak. How can i trace this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. Can you please elaborate on the question. If you want to check for memory patterns of your application checkout this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161315/ruby-ruby-on-rails-memory-leak-detection). Hope it helps :)

Comment: K turns out all the suggestions in the above mentioned link are dead. There is one more [Perftools.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb).